How to conditional format with eazyBI according to the issue status measure
I am using eazyBI in one of my projects to format the color a line diagram/range diagram according to the ticket status. I definitely have the Measure "Issue status" and I also definitely have "Issue status" assuming the value "Closed". I checked that in the table view of eazyBI.
Still, the conditional formatting doesn't seem to have any effect. The complete line diagram always stays in color red even though plenty of Jira Tickets are already closed. I just wanted to see which tickets are still pending and which are closed by color.
https://docs.eazybi.com/eazybi/analyze-and-visualize/create-charts/charts-conditional-formatting

